# Winter bash leaderboard seems to have wrong number of hats

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

I have 2 fewer hats than Stackoverflow says I have, according to the leaderboard for Stackoverflow. I don't think this is just a slow update because it's just updated my leaderboard position and my number of hats on the leaderboard is still wrong.

Do secret hats not count or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are mixing up the Network-wide hats with the site specific hats.

You have 24 total hats, but 2 of the hats you have not earned on Stack Overflow:

[image: Snapshot of hats page]

(Old Hat is the other one that you have not earned on SO).

So your hat count on the site-specific (Stack Overflow) leaderboard is correct, it shows 22 hats:

[image]

But if you look at the network wide leaderboard, it shows all 24 hats:

[image]